# Stream ethereum (ERC20) transactions (node.js)

Tags: transactions, tokens, erc-20, javascript

I would like to get discord message every time when address receive ERC20 token. Is there any way to stream Ethereum transactions?

I tried https://github.com/AlexanderC/ethereum-transaction-stream but it's not working as I want (it start scanning all transactions including old ones).

Answer (score 1):

The code you show has an option to select the range of blocks to search for the transactions:

```
// Creates a new stream.
  // Note that "startblock", "endblock", "ERC20TokenAddress" and "mintOnly" options
  // are only available for "EtherscanHTTP" provider. By including "ERC20TokenAddress"
  // there will be included transactions for ERC20 token only and enabling "mintOnly"
  // option will result in leaving only token minting events.
  // Important: "ERC20TokenAddress" and "mintOnly" options are available only when "includeLogs" enabled
  // Important: the result will INCLUDE transactions from the "startblock"
  const stream = await ets.stream(
    '0x4a1eade6b3780b50582344c162a547d04e4e8e4a'
    /*, startblock, endblock, ERC20TokenAddress, mintOnly */
  );
```

if you are going to search block by block, set the start and end block to the block you are interested in.

Hope this helps